# ArcMap adjacency dissolve question - based on missing data in YR field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, dissolve, union

In my polygon shapefile, that was provided by a govt agency, there are thousands of records with `DATAYR=0` which is entry error.

How do I dissolve/merge/union (doesn’t matter which operation) where `DATAYR=0` and adjacent polygon, for example, is `DATAYR=2010`?

I’ll also run it for `DATYR=2012`, `2014`, `2016` etc up to `2020`.

In other words, dissolve/union/merge with closet non-zero. Must preserve the non-zero data.

Comment: Dissolve or transfer attributes?

Comment: I do not need any attributes from the polys represented by DATAYR = 0. It needs to become DATAYR = <non-zero year> it’s adjacent to.

Comment: Use select to split set in 2. Remove all fields in one and spatial join to second. Append sj to 2nd. Remove matched records in 1st. Repeat until nothing left in 1st.

Comment: Could [Eliminate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm) work?